# How to aggregate column values from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, aggregation

I have a data set in a CSV file. Here is a sample:

```
Time,Location,Companyid,Metrics,Amount

2012Q1,AK_995,A,Sales,8820156.363
2012Q1,AK_995,B,Revenue,28392730.51
2012Q1,AK_995,C,Sales,6980332.166
2012Q1,AK_996,B,Revenue,1894254.13
2012Q1,AK_996,A,Sales,4664103.766
2012Q2,AK_995,C,Sales,7980332.166
```

Here the `time` is the year and quarter, `location` is the state symbol with an ID so each state may have multiple rows with different IDs per `companyid`. What I want to do is that for each `companyid` I want to add all the `amount` for a particular state per specific `time`. For example in above sample `companyid` 1 has two records for `time` `2012Q1` - one for `AK_995` and one for `AK_996`. I want to add amount in these two and just have AK as `location`, to get one record with values `2012Q1,AK,1,13484260.129`. This should be done for each `company` per `time` period for all the states. Note that `amounts` across `time` should not be added as in above sample `companyid` `3` had 2 records for same state but in different `time` period. Also I want to do this only where `Metrics` is `Sales` so I want to remove any row where `Metrics` is other than `Sales` and dont add those amount too in aggregation.

I also want to write the output to another csv file. How can I do this?

**UPDATE SECTION:**

As per suggestion of **@MichaelLaszlo** I have this code. The code seems to have one issue. What I want in the output file is to have all the records for a particular `companyid` to come together. The ordering of records within a `companyid` should be in the increasing order of `time` per `location` wise (records for a particular location come together for a particular `companyid`). So for example if there is a `companyid` `B` then all the records of `companyid` `B` should be together and there order should be as below:

```
companyid,state,time,amount
B,AK,2010Q1,5000
B,AK,2010Q2,5100
B,AK,2010Q3,4300
B,AK,2010Q4,4350
B,AK,2011Q1,5600
```

As you can see above all the records of `companyid` `B` are together and within `companyid` `B` records for a particular `location` are together in the order of `time`. In my current output I get records for all the `companyids` scattered. My current code is:

```
totals = {}

# Aggregate sales by quarter, state, and company.
for row in csv.reader(open('data.csv')):
  if row[3] == 'Sales':
    key = (row[0], row[1][:2], row[2])
    totals[key] = totals.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[4])

# Write aggregated data to file.
with open('aggregated.csv', 'w') as out_file:
  writer = csv.writer(out_file)
  for key, value in totals.items():
    row = list(key) + [value]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

My current sample output is:

```
time,state,companyid,amount
2014Q4,AL_,B,547991592.5101689
2014Q1,NV_,B,387534045.40654004
2012Q3,SC_,A,333657617.05835015
2014Q4,DC_,C,54022786.60577
2014Q3,TN_,B,594121931.7221502
```

As you can see the records for `companyid` `B` are scattered and I want the output in the order I have mentioned above in my update section.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Reading csv can be done as described in: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @haraldkl My problem is that I don't know how to do the aggregation I described in my post above. I know how to read the csv file but its the processing thats troubling me as I am new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To aggregate the data, use a hash. Make keys from tuples of the values that you want to aggregate over.

```
totals = {}

for row in csv.reader(open('data.csv')):
  if row[3] == 'Sales':
    key = (row[2], row[1][:2], row[0])
    totals[key] = totals.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[4])
```

To write to a CSV file, use `csv.writer()` on an open file object. To make rows, convert each hash key to a list and concatenate it with the total sales.

```
import csv

with open('aggregated.csv', 'w') as out_file:
  writer = csv.writer(out_file)
  for key, value in sorted(totals.items()):
    row = list(key) + [value]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

We can put these two operations together into a short script:

```
import csv

totals = {}

# Aggregate sales by company, state, and quarter.
for row in csv.reader(open('data.csv')):
  if row[3] == 'Sales':
    key = (row[2], row[1][:2], row[0])
    totals[key] = totals.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[4])

# Write aggregated data to file.
with open('aggregated.csv', 'w') as out_file:
  writer = csv.writer(out_file)
  for key, value in sorted(totals.items()):
    row = list(key) + [value]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Run the above script and check the resulting file `aggregated.csv`.

Comment: I am having an issue in which the output is coming. I have posted my issue in the updated section of my post above. What I want is to have all the records for a company to be together and within each company the records for a particular state should be together and ordered by the year-quarter

Comment: I've revised my code to incorporate the changes you've described. It required changing two lines: `key = (row[2], row[1][:2], row[0])` and `for key, value in sorted(totals.items()):` Anyway, I suggest that you copy and paste the whole script from my revised answer.

Comment: thanks! Can you help me in explaining how exactly the `key` (especially `row[1][:2]`) is getting formed?

Comment: The key is formed by selecting the third, second, and first element of each row. These correspond to the company ID, location, and quarter respectively. We only want the first two characters of the location, so we use `[:2]` to extract a substring consisting of characters 0 through 1. For example, if `row[1]` is the string `AK_995`, `row[1][:2]` takes out the first two characters, `AK`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the size of your dataset but you should start considering using pandas.
You will benefit from a lot of tools like dataframe creation from csv to group by columns.
At the end you have the flexibility to choose the output and it's really fast.

Edit:
Sorry I only have my phone now but here is how to from a csv and generate a Dataframe : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html
And here is the groupby : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
It would look like :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(r'yourPathToCsv.csv')

data_grouped = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['colAmount'].sum().to_frame()
```

Then you can export the data with the to_csv() function from the Dataframe.

**Update**: the `read_csv` method is now preferred to the `from_csv` method. Here's an updated example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'yourPathToCsv.csv')

data_grouped = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['colAmount'].sum().to_frame()
```

Comment: I will add a sample for you

Comment: an example for the sample data I have posted above will be very helpful for understanding

Answer (score 1):

Simple but not optimal for HUGE data:

```
import csv

source = {}
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    next(csvreader , None) #  skip line
    next(csvreader , None) #  skip line
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[3] != 'Sales':
            continue
        data_date = row[0]
        data_state = row[1].split('_')[0]
        data_company = row[2]
        data_amount = float(row[4])
        if data_date not in source:
            source[data_date] = {}
        if data_state not in source[data_date]:
            source[data_date][data_state] = {}
        if data_company not in source[data_date][data_state]:
            source[data_date][data_state][data_company] = []
        source[data_date][data_state][data_company].append(data_amount)

    for k_date in source:
        for k_state in source[k_date]:
            for k_company in source[k_date][k_state]:
                data = source[k_date][k_state][k_company]
                average = ( sum(data) / len(data) )
                print('%s,%s,%s,%s' % (k_date, k_state, k_company, average))
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Added handling of the empty line

Start by reading your data to a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Remove the empty line:

```
data.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
```

Rename the location column:

```
data['Location'] = data['Location'].apply(
    lambda location: location.split('_')[0]
)
```

Then do the processing and save to file:

```
data[data['Metrics']=='Sales'].groupby(
    ['Time','Location','Companyid']
).sum().to_csv(
    'results.csv'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, wether this is what you are looking for, but you could for example use a dict, to collect the values under the key you are interested in, somewhat like this:

```
agg = {}

for row in dat:
  if row[3] == 'Sales':
    state = row[1][:1]
    old = agg.get((row[0], state, row[2]), 0.0)
    agg[(row[0],state,row[2])] = old + row[4]
```

where dat holds the data from your csv table.